# Password Encrypting a file in .Net with the Windows Store API

Tags: .net, windows, encryption, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I want to encrypt a file on a Windows Store app using a password that the user selects. This would have been a easy task if it was a desktop app but without System.Security I can't figure out how to do it (I tried the Windows.Security but it went over my head).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to encrypt data with a password on WinRT.

Comment: What did you try in Windows.Security and in what way was it over your head? There's an explanation with sample code at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt186496.aspx